# how to execute REST request one by one

Tags: c#, winforms, rest, httpwebrequest, restsharp

i get response of "request 1" , but when request 2 is executed i get Timeout Error
i have tried to execute "request 2" and then executing "request 1" , this time i successfully get Response of both the requests.
this is the code :

```
var client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = "http://api.******.com/login/hostLogin";
client.Authenticator = new DigestAuthenticator("****", "123456");
var request = new RestRequest();
request.AddParameter("username",txtlogin.Text);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

do i need to do something like DISPOSE or CLEARHANDLERS() 
please have a look at my problem and tell me if i need to give more information regarding this.

Comment: From the sample code on http://restsharp.org/ what you're doing looks correct; but there's no second request in your code above - please could you include more of you code so we can see how that request's made; perhaps there's some clue there...

Comment: another request is almost same as given request only baseurl and some parameters are changed
there is no syntax error , what i want to know is that do we have to do some stuff like "dispose" before making another request

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was a known bug. What version of RestSharp are you on? We just released 104.2 so you might want to try that out.

Comment: ok i removed beta versionand installed 104.2 but still i get same problem
see the below code runs correctly only 2 times and third time when i click the button my application is unresponsive , is there some issue in services , here is the code:

var client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = "http://api.xyz.com/servicename";
client.Authenticator = new DigestAuthenticator("user", "12345");
var request = new RestRequest();
request.AddParameter("contactno", 9826012345);
request.AddParameter("key", "abcdegfh");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

timeout if  run this code 3 times

Comment: i got what is the problem, actually when the time difference between two requests is very less may be 1 or 2 Seconds, then third request is not successfull,is there some time limitation between two requests ?